# defining entity framework eager loading in the context rather than query!

Tags: entity-framework-4

i am converting a linq2sql based project to entity framework . i am facing in issue setting the eager loading on the context **(not in query)** . just like i can set dataloadoptions in linq2sql in the context .

any idea ?

P.S
as i said i have to set it in the context and not in query.

Comment: Is ObjectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible. EF doesn't allow this. If you want it you must try to roll your own solution which will hold eager loading definition somewhere and inject includes into query based on those stored definitions.

Comment: it would be a big pain . are you dam sure ?

Comment: Yes, I am. There is no equivalent to `LoadOptions`.

Comment: what about DeleteAllOnSubmit , any alternative for that ?

Comment: You can set each loaded object to deleted state in `ObjectStateManager` or you can use `DeleteObject` method on `ObjectContext` or `ObjectSet`.

Comment: thanks . so if its not loaded i have to first load it from the database? and what about InsertAllOnSubmit?

Comment: Yes entity framework works only with loaded entities. If you want to work with not loaded you must use direct SQL. Insert all just works - you will add objects to context and call SaveChanges.